# Error "Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined" with React Stack Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following the instructions on [React-Stack-Grid](https://github.com/tsuyoshiwada/react-stack-grid#how-to-manually-update-layout-) on how to manually update the grid's layout, but I keep getting the error "*Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined*" on the `gridRef` line in the code below:

```
<StackGrid 
    columnWidth={currentWidth <= 700 ? '50%' : '33.33%'}
    gutterHeight={5}
    gutterWidth={15}
    gridRef={grid => this.grid = grid}
>
    {searchResults.map(item => (
        <AccordionPanel
            title={item.title}
            description={item.description}
            institution={item.institution}
        />
    ))}
</StackGrid>
```

And again when trying to execute the `updateLayout()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using Functional Component and Hooks.

Maybe you can try using useRef hook :

```js
const grid = React.useRef(null);
```

And then, set the reference like that :

```js
<StackGrid {...} gridRef={grid}>
```